# ¿Cómo paso una variable de php (que es una url) a javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, csv, highcharts

Tengo la siguiente variable en php, que es una url está construida con texto y variables que vienen desde un formulario, y que leen un csv:

```
<?php $url = "http://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.tsindico.cgi?outtype=xcl&page=pageFrame&header=Coyhaique".htmlspecialchars($especial)."opath=./RXI/".$_POST["e_cod"]."/Cal/".$_POST["mat"].htmlspecialchars($especial)."o=./RXI/".$_POST["e_cod"]."/Cal/".$_POST["mat"]."/".$_POST["mat"].".horario.horario.ic&from=".$date_from_final.$_POST["hora_desde"]."00&to=".$date_to_final.$_POST["hora_hasta"]."00&path=/usr/airviro/data/CONAMA/&";?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que una funcion fopen (dentro de un Highcharts) que viene mas abajo sea capaz de trabajar con esa url.
La funcion es la siguiente:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Registros validados',
    data: [<?php $numeros = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
    if (($handle = fopen('datos.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($data[2] == '' OR !in_array($data[2][0], $numeros)){
        $data[2] = 'null';}
    print_r($data[2].",");
}
fclose($handle);}?>]
},
```

Comment: Que tal si usas ajax o simplementa incrustas ese codigo de php dentro del mismo file donde creas el chart??? Asumiendo que este ultimo sea uno de php claro esta

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que construyas tu propio array en PHP:

```
$series = [
    'name' => 'Registros validados',
    'data' => []
];
// código para rellenar $series['data'] a partir del CSV
```

Y al final, donde escribes el JavaScript:

```
series = <?php echo json_encode($series); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Porqué no tomas la url directamente desde javascript con:

```
window.location.href
```

Luego utilizando la función [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) podrás dividir la cadena según aglún caracter en particular.

Claramente creando una nueva variable del estilo:

```
var nuevaVariable = window.location.href.split(´&´)
```